# Canonical Transformation and Symplectic Conditions

Tags: classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry, canonical-transformation, hamilton-equations

I have one question regarding Canonical transformation and symplectic matrix. 
I have read some notions from the following note:

http://www.chim.unifi.it/orac/MAN/node6.html

For me it is not clear how it is obtained the following  relation:

$$\dot y = MJM^t \frac{\partial H}{\partial y}.$$

Can you explain me, please.

**Update1**

What I have tried.

I'll consider the  case when $n=2$.

We try to make a transformation $y \to y(x)$.

relation 1(a): 
$$\dot y = \frac{\partial y}{\partial  x} \dot x $$
relation 2(a):
$$\dot x = J \frac{\partial H}{\partial x}$$
**BUT**

relation 3(a):
$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$$

So, we have:

$$\dot y= \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \dot x = \frac{\partial y}{\partial  x} J \frac{\partial H}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial  x} J\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}.$$

From here I get stuck.

Looks similar but I don't know how to continue to obtain same form.

I don't know why there appear the transpose of that matrix.

Can you help me to write in coordinates $\displaystyle \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$.

**UPDATE2**

from relation 1(a):

$$\dot y = \frac{\partial y }{\partial x} \dot x $$
In matrix notation, for $n=2$, I'll have:
relation (1b)

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\dot y_{1}\\ \dot y_{2}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_{1}}{\partial x_{1}}& \frac{\partial y_{1}}{\partial x_{2}}\\
\frac{\partial y_{2}}{\partial x_{1}}&\frac{\partial y_{2}}{\partial x_{2}}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\dot x_1\\\dot x_2
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, From relation 3(a) I want to obtain in a matrix form relation 3(b):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_1}\\
\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_2}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial y_1}\\
\frac{\partial H}{\partial y_2}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_2}\\
\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_2}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

So,the relation from **UPDATE1**

$$\dot y=\frac{\partial y}{\partial  x} J\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}.$$

will become: 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\dot y_{1}\\ \dot y_{2}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_{1}}{\partial x_{1}}& \frac{\partial y_{1}}{\partial x_{2}}\\
\frac{\partial y_{2}}{\partial x_{1}}&\frac{\partial y_{2}}{\partial x_{2}}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial y_1}\\
\frac{\partial H}{\partial y_2}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_2}\\
\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_2}
\end{pmatrix} $$

And from here, again, it seems impossible for me... more and more, the matrix multiplication is not possible...

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Start with the case where the dimension is 2, and write down the system of equations. Then apply to that system an arbitrary (not necessarily canonical) change of coordinates to see what happens.

Comment: ok. I will try and I stop I will ask you. thanks!

Comment: I have tried something. I hope it is ok what I have did.

Comment: Hint to the question (v4):  In matrix notation, be careful with what are rows and what are columns.

Comment: You actually did for any dimension, write it down using $y=\left(\begin{array}{c}y_1 \\ y_2\end{array}\right)$. Then you will understand Qmechanic's comment about tracking columns and rows.

Comment: OK. I will try again. I hope I'll obtain the good results. Thanks!

Comment: @CvZ
It is ok what I did. Can you help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: @Qmechanic It is ok what I did. Can you help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Your difficulty lies is the relation 3(b). Try to multiply the matrices in that relation and you will see that you are doing something wrong... then try to write it in a way that it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you're still interested in this, but here goes.

Take the coordinate transformation $\vec{x}\to\vec{y}(\vec{x})$, i.e. we consider $\vec{y}$ to be a function of $\vec{x}$.
Let the Hamiltonian function in terms of the new coordinates be denoted $\tilde{H}$, that is, $\tilde{H}(\vec{y}(\vec{x}))=H(\vec{x})$.

Rather than doing the calculation in terms of matrices, it is easier to do it in terms of components (tensor notation). Then you don't have to worry about tracking rows/columns, and also the notation is a lot more compact. Let $y_i$ denote the $i$'th component of $\vec{y}$, etc. Also, $M_{ij}$ denotes the $ij$ component of the $M$ matrix, which is $\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}$ (there is a typo in the definition of $M$ in your link).
Our goal is to show
$$\dot{y}_i=\left(M J M^T \frac{\partial H}{\partial \vec{y}}\right)_i.$$

Consider the LHS above, $\frac{d}{dt}\left(y_i (\vec{x}(t))\right)$. By the chain rule, this is equal to 
$$\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{dx_j}{dt}$$ 
with implicit summation over $j$. But $\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}=M_{ij}$, so
$$\dot{y}_i=\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{dx_j}{dt}=M_{ij}\dot{x}_j=(M\dot{\vec{x}})_i$$
$$\implies \dot{\vec{y}}=M\dot{\vec{x}}=MJ\frac{\partial H}{\partial \vec{x}}.$$

Now recalling $H(\vec{x})=\tilde{H}(\vec{y}(\vec{x}))$, apply the chain rule to get
$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial \tilde{H}(\vec{y})}{\partial y_j}\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_i}=M_{ji}\frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial y_j}=(M^T)_{ij}\frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial y_j}=\left(M^T \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial \vec{y}}\right)_i$$
$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial \vec{x}}=M^T \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial \vec{y}}.$$

Substitute this into the above gives
$$\dot{\vec{y}}=MJM^T\frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial\vec{y}}$$
as required.